# Al darle play el personaje se mueve solo en el eje X

Tags: c#, unity3d, unity2d

Poco más que añadir, cuando en unity le doy play a la escena automaticamente el personaje se sale de plano moviendose solo en el eje X.
Aqui os dejo el código.
Gracias de antemano

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;

public class Move_Script : MonoBehaviour
{
    Animator an;
    SpriteRenderer mySpriteRenderer;
    Rigidbody2D rb;
    float movementDir;
    float speed;
    bool canJump;
    void Start()
    {
        movementDir = 1.0f;
        speed = 250.0f;
        an = gameObject.GetComponent<Animator>();
        rb = gameObject.GetComponent<Rigidbody2D>();
    }

    private void Awake()
    {
        mySpriteRenderer = GetComponent<SpriteRenderer>();
    }


    void Update()
    {
        Vector2 currentVel = rb.velocity;

        //*****************JUMP***************************

        if (Input.GetKeyDown(KeyCode.Space) && canJump)
        {
            canJump = false;
            an.SetInteger("state", 2);
            gameObject.GetComponent<Rigidbody2D>().AddForce(new Vector2(0, 300f));
        }


        //**************MOVE RIGHT*************************

        if (Input.GetKey(KeyCode.RightArrow))
        {
            an.SetInteger("state", 1);
            mySpriteRenderer.flipX = false;
            currentVel.x = 1.0f;
            if (Input.GetKey(KeyCode.LeftShift))
            {
                an.SetInteger("state", 3);
                currentVel.x = 2.0f;
            }
        }

        //***************MOVE LEFT**************************

        else if (Input.GetKey(KeyCode.LeftArrow))
        {
            mySpriteRenderer.flipX = true;
            an.SetInteger("state", 1);
            currentVel.x = -1.0f;
            if (Input.GetKey(KeyCode.LeftShift))
            {
                an.SetInteger("state", 3);
                currentVel.x = -2.0f;
            }
        }

        else
        {
            an.SetInteger("state", 0);
            currentVel.x = 0;
        }

        movementDir = Input.GetAxis("Horizontal");
        rb.AddForce(new Vector3(movementDir, 0.0f, 0.0f) * speed * Time.deltaTime);
        rb.velocity = currentVel;

    }


    private void OnTriggerStay2D(Collider2D other)
    {
        if (other.gameObject.tag == "ground")
        {
            canJump = true;
        }

    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ya está arreglado, sin querer añadí un box collider al background y por eso sacaba el personaje de la escena. Gracias de todas formas compañero! ;)

Answer (score 1):

La función Update() se ejecuta a cada frame por lo tanto esta constantemente ejecutandose. En ella tienes esta linia de código sin ningún tipo de condición:

```
rb.AddForce(new Vector3(movementDir, 0.0f, 0.0f) * speed * Time.deltaTime);
```

Siendo `movementDir = 1.0f` y `speed = 250f` según lo que tienes declarado en el `Start()` eso quiere decir que a cada frame le añades velocidad en las X y por eso al darle al play tu personaje se mueve.